# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL port: "*************"

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, retrofit

This is my url in Network Module:

```
 private const val BASE_URL = "http://localhost:192.168.29.20/api/"
```

I got this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL port: "*************"

Comment: Can you use that URL in a browser? It looks like an odd syntax, having "localhost" AND the four-numbers version where I would otherwise expect a port. Maybe that is exactly what the error is trying to tell you.

Comment: `192.168.29.20` is not a valid port.

Comment: Because thats not a valid url? What would an IP Address in the port section of the url mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `"http://Your_4numbers:Your_Port/api/"`.

Probably you want something like

`"http://192.168.29.20:some_number/api/"` where "some_number" is for the port you are trying to use.